# How do I remove an item from the Gnome-classic panel?

Tags: gnome-panel

How do I remove an item from the Gnome-classic top panel?  Pressing Alt and then clicking the right mouse button only gives me an option for adding an item.  There is no option for removing an item.

Answer (score 5):

Hold down 'alt'+'super' then right click on the icon you want to remove.

In the context menu that follows from your click, you will see 2 options, 'move' or 'remove from panel'; and these are your options.